# Which child does jquery pick if there are multiple children?

Tags: jquery

I have a unordered list `<ul id="images" >`. There are 3 list items in the list and in each item there is an image. Each image has a different width. How does jquery deal with the following.

```
var width = $('#images li img').width();
```

which of the 3 image widths will the var 'width' contain?

Comment: It returns the `width` of first `element` among `selected set`.

Comment: @joy if you turn that into an answer I will accept it

Comment: Reading the documentation would have answered this for you: ["Description: Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements."](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It returns the width of first element among selected set of elements.

Read more on [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

It will return the width of the first matched element - http://jsfiddle.net/FGchc/

Answer (score 1):

The description for the [`width` method](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> "Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements."

So, it will return the width of the first of the matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

The first image's width. And jQuery works depth first so in the following:

```
<div><img></div>
<img>
```

The `img` inside div will be the first `img`.